# Memory usage of log4j2 AsyncLogger

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am using the following config for `log4j2` and noticing that log statements get stored in-memory before being flushed to disk.  Is there a setting to control how many messages get stored in-memory before being flushed to disk?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" name="TestApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="logs/test.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB"/> 
      </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
      <AsyncLogger name="FATAL_LOGGER" level="fatal" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">  
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
    </AsyncLogger>
    <Root level="debug" includeLocation="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: More people seem interested in editing rather than actually answering.  I know editing is important but I don't think anyone (who knew the answer) misunderstood the actual question based on its original format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the [AsyncLogger.RingBufferSize](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) value (Defaults to `256*1024` & minimum is `128`).  This should help configure how many objects get allocated before being flushed to disk.

Comment: what is the best way of setting it up - config or system properties?  is there a working example?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can control the buffer size but you cannot control how many messages get stored in-memory before being flushed to disk. This is a function of how fast these messages get produced versus how fast they are consumed. If your queue size is too small and your buffer becomes full during a burst, the call to logger.log(...) will block until space is available in the buffer again. So be careful about making the size too small, unless you are on a platform with very little memory (embedded or phone or so).

Comment: thanks!!  I'm using small VMs (cannot change that now) and hence memory is limited.  I still prefer to use this route but just with a smaller buffer with more frequent writes to disk.  Testing now

Comment: also, can you please comment - what is the best approach for handling this - via config or system properties

Comment: The Async Logger ringbuffer size can only be configured via system properties at the moment.

Comment: thank you - will this work or do I need to do something else: System.setProperty("AsyncLoggerConfig.RingBufferSize", "128 * 1024");

Comment: You need to put the actual integer: 131072